# Iterate over all possible combinations of list elements and use as indices in Python

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
indices = [125,144,192]
```

I want to generate such a structure that I want to use any combination of three of these numbers as indices for a 3d list:

```
myList[i][j][k] = someVar
```

where `i`,`j`, and `k` loop over all of the combinations shown below:

```
i,j,k = 0,0,0
i,j,k = 0,0,192
i,j,k = 0,144,0
i,j,k = 125,0,0
i,j,k = 0,144,192
i,j,k = 125,0,192
i,j,k = 125,144,0
i,j,k = 125,144,192
```

In other words, I'd like to simplify the following:

```
for i in [0,125]:
    for j in  [0,144]:
        for k in [0,192]:
            myList[i][j][k] = someVar
```

What would be a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: It's already very good, what do you think you can simplify?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was already a way to do this in Python, and also I may have to repeat this a couple of times within my code, also for larger lists: `[1,2,3,...,124]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` :

```
>>> list(product([0,125],[0,144],[0,192]))
[(0, 0, 0), 
 (0, 0, 192), 
 (0, 144, 0), 
 (0, 144, 192), 
 (125, 0, 0), 
 (125, 0, 192), 
 (125, 144, 0), 
 (125, 144, 192)]
```

Or as a more general solution you can use `izip` (in python 3 `zip` is efficient ) and `repeat` to create the desire pairs and then pass them to `product` :

```
>>> indices = [125,144,192]
>>> from itertools import product,izip,repeat
>>> list(product(*izip(repeat(0,len(indices)),indices)))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 192), (0, 144, 0), (0, 144, 192), (125, 0, 0), (125, 0, 192), (125, 144, 0), (125, 144, 192)]
>>>
```

And for indexing you can do :

```
for i,j,k in product(*izip(repeat(0,len(indices)),indices)):
    # do stuff with myList[i][j][k]
```

Comment: Would it then make sense to do the following: `for element in indexList: i,j,k = element` and then `myList[i][j][k]`, or is there a way to use tuples to directly access an element in the list?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate You can use multi-unpacking, check the edit!

Answer (score 1):

Seems more ambiguous but...

```
for triple in [(x,y,z) for x in [0,125] for y in [0,144] for z in [0,192]]:
    myList[ triple[0] ][ triple[1] ][ triple[2] ] = somevar
```